How to clean & repair this grout?
I know there has been a lot of discussion before about repairing grout lines.  I hope my question here is different enough to merit a new message.
I have some grout lines between glass tiles which make up the wall of my shower.  They don't seem to be leaking, but they're definitely cracking.  I think this is Sand grout, but I'm not sure.  I'm hoping someone can recognize it from the included photo.  If it is, it looks to me as though it either wasn't sealed or was sealed such a long time ago that it needs to be done again.
I'm undecided whether I should use urethane, epoxy, or just sand grount here (obviously after removing loose bits and cleaning the remainder).  I'm in southern California, so we do get a few small earthquakes.  I was thinking urethane may be best for that reason, and I have read it can be applied over sand grout as long as the depth is more than about 2mm.  This depth looks to be a bit more than 2mm.  If I use sand grout, then I could seal everything evenly, of course.
I'm interested in opinions and other people's experiences.
Thanks for any help you can provide!


Regrout it. It looks like sanded grout based on the texture and the width of seam. Urethane isn't going to help even in a minor earthquake. You can use it to seal but you might have trouble matching the color.

You have sanded grout.  You are correct it was not properly sealed.
I would regrout with the same color sanded grout. Let it dry for at least 24 hours then use an impregnator sealer.  This type of sealer seeps deep into the grout, sealing the pores. It does not just seal the surface.

Thanks!  I really appreciate all of the responses.  I'll look into sanded grout and sealer.
